# Testing Android with JUnit - Test artifact in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test Android application using jUnit and Mockito. I've added this lines to gradle:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

Now I am wondering which Test Artifact in Build Variant should I choose.It is possible to choose `Unit Tests 
 Android Instrumentation Tests`.
Though I have tests in properly path Android Studio cannot find test when Android Instrumentation Test is set in Build Variant. On the other hand, when Unit Tests option is set it is hard using test Frameworks typical for Android(Like MockContext). It's not possible to compile project properly.
Morover, is anyone know what is difference beetwen AndroidTest and test folder name? 
Thank you in Advance!

Comment: The instrumentation tests (functional tests) comes under androidTest while the uni tests comes under test folder.

Comment: Maybe should you take a look at [Android Testing -Android Dev Summit 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdasFFfXKOY)